# Why doesn't this Javascript prototype get overwriten

Tags: javascript, prototypal-inheritance

I am looking at the example here [Using apply to chain constructors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)

I understand it except for this line:

```
fNewConstr.prototype = fConstructor.prototype;
```

Why is it necessary and why does it not make it lose the function that was just defined for fNewConstr?

```
Function.prototype.construct = function (aArgs) {
    var fConstructor = this, fNewConstr = function () { fConstructor.apply(this, aArgs); };
    // Why doesn't fNewConstr.prototype get completely overwritten?
    fNewConstr.prototype = fConstructor.prototype;
    return new fNewConstr();
};



function MyConstructor () {
    for (var nProp = 0; nProp < arguments.length; nProp++) {
        this["property" + nProp] = arguments[nProp];
    }
}

var myArray = [4, "Hello world!", false];
var myInstance = MyConstructor.construct(myArray);

alert(myInstance.property1); // alerts "Hello world!"
alert(myInstance instanceof MyConstructor); // alerts "true"
alert(myInstance.constructor); // alerts "MyConstructor"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean, why doesn't `fNewConstr` (the function) get overwritten when you write

```
fNewConstr.prototype = ...;
```

...the answer is because nothing is overwriting it. That code just sets the `prototype` property of the function.

If your question is: Why doesn't `fNewConstr` get *recreated* each time `construct` is called, the answer is: It is.

Comment: I see that fNewConstr gets recreated, but it looks to me that since it is being assigned the prototype of the original function-object, it should only now contain the code defined in MyConstructor

Comment: @getit: It contains the same code it did prior to that assignment: `fConstructor.apply(this, aArgs);` The contents of a constructor function and the contents of the object assigned to its `prototype` are completely unrelated (except that they usually rely on one another).

Comment: Ok, I think I get it, I was being dumb, thanks. It's doing that so that no matter what function calls the new construct function, it will retain it's initial prototype, For example, I could make a new function, MyConstructor2, with it's own properties, and construct would work with both. Right?

Comment: @getit: Yes, because it's using `fConstructor = this` and so `fConstructor` will be the function on which you call the `construct` function. BTW, you might find my [`Lineage`](http://code.google.com/p/lineagejs/) library interesting.